# unable to produce R.java , i kept targetSDK 17 in both the manifest and also cleaned the projects several time

Tags: android

```
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:89: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:43: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:51: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionMode'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:184: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:183: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:spinnerMode'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:63: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:70: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:258: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:animationResolution'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:78: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:85: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:90: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:309: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:96: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:100: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:102: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:106: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:117: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:119: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:22: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\LSMobile\branches\V2.0\LSMobileAppChiefs\res\values-v11\styles.xml:16: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:homeAsUpIndicator'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\LSMobile\branches\V2.0\LSMobileAppChiefs\res\values-v14\styles.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarStyle'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\LSMobile\branches\V2.0\LSMobileAppChiefs\res\values-v11\styles.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:homeAsUpIndicator'.
[2014-05-12 16:08:23 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\LSMobile\branches\V2.0\LSMobileAppChiefs\res\values-v11\styles.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:89: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:43: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:51: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionMode'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:184: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:183: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:spinnerMode'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:63: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:70: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-05-12 17:13:41 - LSMobileAppChiefs] D:\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5a15d92\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow'.

[
```

Comment: Do you really think that anybody would be able to help you just from an error message?

Comment: i added sherlock actionbar library in my project.. when i add it R file get deleted automatically..

Comment: Still not enough to diagnose the problem. How is anyone supposed to help you just from that information?

Answer (score 0):

New R file is not getting created. Possible reasons could be

1> You might not have added action bar properly in xml.

2> Not using proper imports.

Need more part of your code to understand better. Also you need not modify both manifest files, just do your changes in the one that is in the first level of your project directory.